# SSH Server is running but not visible on network

Tags: ssh, sshd

My ssh server is running on port 2224. I am running two ssh servers, sshd on 22 and sshd2 on 2224

```
bash-3.2# /etc/init.d/sshd2 status
openssh-daemon (pid  19737) is running...


bash-3.2# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2012-09-07 05:14 IST
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is  disabled.     
Interesting ports on telnets.nith.ac.in (127.0.0.1):
Not shown: 1671 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
631/tcp  open  ipp
646/tcp  open  unknown
3306/tcp open  mysql
8443/tcp open  https-alt

bash-3.2# netstat -nap |grep 2224
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:2224   0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN           19737/sshd2
```

Answer (score 3):

`nmap` actually only scans a couple thousand of the "most common" ports by default. Evidently, port 2224 doesn't make the cut. Look into the `-p` option if you want to scan a particular range of ports.

Comment: When i try connecting to server through localhost, it works fine, but when i try connecting from other PC, it shows no route to host, if i use the port 2224

Comment: It's possible your institution blocks external traffic to most ports for security reasons. This seems to be an increasingly common practice, and I can't blame them. Is there a particular reason you need to run an `sshd` on this other port?